# Maximum value of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find maximum value of the sequence $\left\{\frac{9^n}{n!}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$              .
As n tends to infinity the limit of the sequence goes to zero. And initially the value of the n-th term increases when we increase n . But I could not understand from where the value of the n-th term will tend to fall?

Comment: Consider the ratio of two consecutive terms.  The sequence is positive, so it decreases precisely when the ratio falls below 1.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=9^n/n!$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{9}{n+1}\,a_n.
$$
The factor $9/(n+1)$ is bigger or equal to $1$ when $n\le8$, and smaller than $1$ when $n>8$. Thus
$$
a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4<a_5<a_6<a_7<a_8=a_9>a_{10}>a_{11}>\dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

From an algebraic point of view, we could consider $$f(x)=\frac {9^x}{x!}=\frac {9^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}$$ and compute its derivative. Doing so, we can find a maximum value for $x=8.49538$.

With integers, use hardmath's suggestion and find $n=8$ and $n=9$ as explained by 
Julián Aguirre